# Filtered drop-down on Newform?

Tags: list

I have share point 2010 and SPD 2010, and have no ability to use downloads etc...

My issue is I have one list, and I want to have a drop-down on new form, that displays the names of people (in column A) where the flag in column B equals "yes"

I have tried everything, and cannot seem to get it to work - so any help would be fantastic.

Many thanks

.....

Sorry Andrey, yes as you have indicated but I only have one list with column A and B and I want to filter the newitem drop down on that list ( not a different list).

And I do not have access to infopath...

Comment: It would be great if you elaborate your question, i.e. include screenshots/mockups if you can't explain it with words. I'm afraid the question is very foggy as of now. My best bet would be that you need a filtered lookup field. So you have a list of people, there you have columns A and B, and on some other list's new form you want to have dropdown with those people, but not all of them - just those who have "yes" in column B? Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

Such behaviour could be easily achieved by using InfoPath for Edit forms, which shall enable you to use Actions to filter values displayed in another column based on selection, example here https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/creating-filtered-lookups-in-sharepoint-2010-with-infopath-2010.aspx

Of course, beyond this, if you still intend to stay with ASPX forms you would need to consider injecting some Javascript code, via another CE-WP and start coding - it could get messy!